# Storing multiple rows from MySQL in separate variables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am writing a web application in PHP which will store employee data and generate employee ID cards to PDF. I am using FPDF for creation of PDFs and that works fine. I am having a problem with showing results from MySQL database.

I have to generate PDF with 4 employee ID cards and I am not sure how to get them from the database. So far I am using LIMIT option in the query to get only 4 results and i will have an if statement based on mysql.php?id=1 id which will define the limit. It is a little messy but there are not going to be more than 80 employees.

This is my code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id == 1) {
$limit_start = 0;
$limit_end = 4;
}

$result=mysql_query("SELECT users.tajemnik, users.dateCreated, users.showmeID,     
users.workerName, users.dateCreated, users.workerPlace, users.workerSID, uploads.userID, uploads.data, uploads.filetype
 FROM users INNER JOIN uploads ON users.showmeID = uploads.userID ORDER BY workerName DESC LIMIT $limit_start, $limit_end") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") or die('Spojení se nezdařilo');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$workerName = $row["workerName"];
$workerPlace = $row["workerPlace"];
$workerSID = $row["workerSID"];
$tajemnik = $row["tajemnik"];
$showmeID = $row["showmeID"];
$mysqldatetime = strtotime($row['dateCreated']);
$image = $row["data"];

$phpdatetime = date("d.m.Y",$mysqldatetime);

}
```

This will get me the first result from the query. I need to get information from all 4 rows and have them stored in variables like $workerName1, $workerName2 etc. I hope it makes sense what I am trying to do.

Thank you for your replies!
V.

Comment: Do you simply want to take first 4 notes? If so `LIMIT 4` is enough.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @Truth thanks for the reading, i certainly do care and want to learn new stuff! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get variables like $workerName1, $workerName2 etc

Nope, you don't.
You actually need an array.

So, first, get yourself a function

```
function sqlArr($sql){
  $ret = array();
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
  if ($res) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      $ret[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

then write a code

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") or die('Spojení se nezdařilo');
$sql = "SELECT users.tajemnik, users.dateCreated, users.showmeID, users.workerName, 
               users.dateCreated, users.workerPlace, users.workerSID, uploads.userID, 
               uploads.data, uploads.filetype
        FROM users 
        INNER JOIN uploads ON users.showmeID = uploads.userID 
        ORDER BY workerName DESC LIMIT $limit_start, $limit_end";
$data = sqlArr($sql);
```

Now you have all your data in the `$data` *array*.
So, you can loop over it or access single values like

```
echo $data[0]['tajemnik'];
```

or

```
foreach($data as $row) {
  //do whatever you want with database row
  echo $row['tajemnik'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly. I was hoping there can be a solution! Thanks again!